# * Vs ++ precedence in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am not able to understand the output of the following C code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
   char * something = "something";
   printf("%c", *something++);  // s
   printf("%c", *something);    // o
   printf("%c", *++something);  // m
   printf("%c", *something++);  // m
}
```

Please help :)

Comment: Why don't you include the output as well?

Comment: When writing code like this it is good to add some () to add readability since it much more clear what you like to happen with  *(something++) or (*something)++.

Comment: @Johan: yeah, I always have to look up if ++ or * is higher... and that after over 10 years of  c++ ;-) I always do *(++something)

Comment: if any of the answers helped you, you shoul accept the answer ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// main entrypoint
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char * something = "something";

    // increment the value of something one type-width (char), then
    //  return the previous value it pointed to, to be used as the 
    //  input for printf.
    // result: print 's', something now points to 'o'.
    printf("%c", *something++);

    // print the characer at the address contained in pointer something
    // result: print 'o'
    printf("%c", *something);

    // increment the address value in pointer something by one type-width
    //  the type is char, so increase the address value by one byte. then
    //  print the character at the resulting address in pointer something.
    // result: something now points at 'm', print 'm'
    printf("%c", *++something);

    // increment the value of something one type-width (char), then
    //  return the previous value it pointed to, to be used as the 
    //  input for printf.
    // result: print 's', something now points to 'o'.
    printf("%c", *something++);
}
```

Result:

```
somm
```

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon *fantastic* name, sir.

Answer (score 6):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence for details

```
printf("%c", *something++);
```

Gets the char at *something and then increments it ('s')

```
printf("%c", *something);
```

Just get the char (now the second, due to the increment in the last statement ('o')

```
printf("%c", *++something);
```

increment and then get the char of the new position ( 'm' )

```
printf("%c", *something++);
```

Gets the char at *something and then increments it ('m')

Answer (score 6):

It is pretty simple.

```
char * something = "something";
```

Assignment of pointer.

```
printf("%c\n", *something++);//equivalent to *(something++)
```

Pointer is incremented but the value before increment is dereferenced ans it is post-increment.

```
printf("%c\n", *something);//equivalent to *(something)
```

Pointer is now pointing to 'o' after increment in the previous statement.

```
printf("%c\n", *++something);//equivalent to *(++something)
```

Pointer is incremented to point to 'm' and dereferenced after incrementing the pointer as this is pre-increment.

```
printf("%c\n", *something++);//equivalent to *(something++)
```

Same as the first answer.
Also notice `'\n'` at the end of every string in printf. It makes the output buffer flush and makes the line print. Always use a `\n` at the end of your printf.

You may want to look at **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255147/does-p-increment-after-dereferencing)** as well.

Answer (score 0):

always use the clockwise rule [clockwise rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

```
printf("%c\n", *something++);
```

according to the rule you will first encounter * so get the value then ++ means increment

[image]

in the 3rd case  `printf("%c\n", *something++);`

[image]

so according to the image increment the value ++ and then get the value *

Comment: That's a good reference, but it's for types in declarations, not operators in expressions.

Comment: I tried it in this case and its working fine according to above solution I gave above. but you are right its for declarations. apologies if the answer is misleading