# Operations on Pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[] = "hello";
    char *ptr = a;
    printf ("%c\n",*ptr++);//it prints character 'h'.
    printf ("%c\n",*ptr);//it prints character 'e'.
    return 0;
}
```

As I understand it: In the above code, in `*ptr++` expression, both `*` and `++` have same precedence and operation  will take place from right to left, which means pointer will increment first and deference will happen next. So it should print the character `'e'` in the first `printf` statement. But it is not.

So my question is: Where will it store the incremented value (in, `*ptr++`) if it is not dereferencing that location in first `printf` statement?

Comment: That's not a doubt. You can't doubt something that you don't understand.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338730/vs-precedence-in-c/13338801#13338801) and see if you still don't get it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ptr++` means "increment `ptr`, but return the pre-increment value."

Thus despite the fact that the increment happens first, it is the *original*, non-incremented pointer that is being dereferenced.

By contrast, if your precedence reasoning is correct, `*++ptr` should print `e` as you expect. `++ptr` means "increment `ptr` and return the post-increment value".

Answer (score 0):

Whatever happens is correct.

When doing *ptr ++ it just takes the *ptr value and performs operation as it is a post increment and had you used ++ *ptr it would have printed e in the very first place.

Comment: pretty sure you meant `*++p`

Comment: Ha ha ha. Yeah. Typo Sorry for that :)

Answer (score 0):

p++ is post increment while ++p is pre increment. p++ gives the values of p and then increments the contents of p while ++p increments the contents of p and then returns the value  of p

Answer (score 0):

It will be stored in the pointer ptr itself. It is like making the ptr point to the next byte that it used to point:

```
ptr = ptr + 1;
```

Comment: ptr = ptr + 1 means Pointer is incremented means pointing to next location and deference of that (ptr = ptr + 1) location is 'e' na, then why it is giving 'h' only in first printf statement

Comment: Because the increase by 1 byte is done after the execution of printf.

Answer (score -2):

yupp, pointer will be autoamticaly incremented after each use.

Comment: The question is rathen "when" it will be incremented. In layman's terms `++i` means first increment, then return, while `i++` means first return value, then increment.

Comment: "after each use"? seriously?