# how to interpret the operator's priority in *d++=*s++

Tags: c

I was confused by the expression `*d++=*s++`. How to undertand it.

```
int main()
{
    char s[20]="hello,world";
    char d[20];
    char *src=s;
    char *des=d;
    while(*src) *des++=*src++;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not again - somebody writing code that is incomprehensible and difficult to understand and therefore requires asking a question on SO. Why not separate it into multiple lines so that it is readable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does *p++ increment after dereferencing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9255147/1708801)

Comment: Why don't you put a `printf()` before `*des++=*src++` and after and observer the changes of `src` and `des` of the pointer position and values?  It let you have a better understanding how it runs.

Comment: @Ed, it can't be incomprehendable _and_ difficult to understand - the former indicates that it's not difficult to understand but _impossible_ :-) Sorry, couldn't resist. In any case, if it's meant to copy the array or a C string, it's also wrong: in both cases it doesn't copy enough (the whole array for an array copy, the terminator for a string).

Comment: @EdHeal: `*des++=*src++`, while it may be terse, is a pretty standard C idiom.  I'm pretty sure it appears in K&R I.

Answer (score 5):

It has the same behavior as:

```
*dest = *src;
 dest++;
 src++;
```

That is copy the character pointed at by `src` to the character pointed at by `dest`. Then move each pointer to the next character element.